# How to create table view with rows and columns? xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am creating an iPhone application I need

1. tableview with rows and column
2. and fetch the rows and column data from mysql database

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Right now it's difficult to tell what exactly you want to achieve, you should provide more information to your question. There are 2 options for you if you want to find an answer: **1.** improve your question and post what exactly you want to achieve and what have you tried; **2.** google.it

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you target iOS 6 or later then you should use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for this purpose. It looks like a simple grid and much easier to manage than UITableView with 'rows and columns'.

Answering your second question then you might look into [Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started), simplifying definition - its entity based database engine built on SQL(in most cases).

There is complete [tutorial](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/full-core-data-application.html) how to combine em.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As standard iOS doesn't support tables with columns although (as @Mehdzor says) UICollectionView sort of does this.

To be honest if you can't make UITableView fit your needs then you are probably going to have to either design your own table or use a third party framework. Apple have done this when they developed Numbers for iOS but you have to be careful when you are working with small screens.

For your second question CoreData is brilliant. I use it myself for several projects and it is really easy to use. It really comes into its own when you get to synchronising devices via iCloud (a really, really, really difficult thing to do from scratch).

The only downside to CoreData is that it is controlled entirely by the Apple framework. As such you cannot easily port your app onto other systems. Other alternatives are things like [Parse](https://parse.com), or (if cloud synchronisation isn't necessary) you can control your own databases using the [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) library. Although `sqlite3` for Apple is written in C, it's not bad to use once you get your head round it.

EDIT: If your mySQL database is on a server then you could just use web services to query your database and let the server side logic do the actual work.